# convert JSON in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
var app = angular.module('statisticsApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  "use strict";
  return $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "GatewayAPI.php",

  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
    $scope.records = response.data;
    console.log($scope.records.data);

    var mydata, myobj;

    mydata = $scope.records.data;
    myobj = JSON.parse(mydata);

    console.log(myobj);

  });

});
```

JSON FILE

```
{"timestamp":1526524809413,"data":[{"_id":"rJeixnNtpG","data":"N11B00074","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,52],"timestamp":1525398515116},{"_id":"HkzognEYpf","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398515479},{"_id":"BJxXp4t6M","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398807747},{"_id":"H1xlXTNYaG","data":"N11B00075","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,53],"timestamp":1525398808426},{"_id":"SyZX6NY6G","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398809027},{"_id":"BJG7p4Fpf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398809647},{"_id":"SyX7aVKpz","data":"N11B00075","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,55,53],"timestamp":1525398811068},{"_id":"SJLm6EFTG","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398813668},{"_id":"SkPm64YaG","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525398814984},{"_id":"B1lvXp4KpM","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525398814985},{"_id":"SkyQAEKaz","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399063068},{"_id":"Skx17AEYTG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399063107},{"_id":"HJ-JQCEYTG","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399063327},{"_id":"H1fk7CEYaf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399063367},{"_id":"HkeQCNKTG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399064227},{"_id":"Skxl7ANtpM","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399064268},{"_id":"B1ZmAVYpG","data":"N11E0000\u0012","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,18],"timestamp":1525399064847},{"_id":"rkx-m0VYpf","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399065209},{"_id":"SJN4A4tTG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399084327},{"_id":"rkINCNKpG","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399085827},{"_id":"HyP4CVFpf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399087089},{"_id":"Byu4CVYaG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399087847},{"_id":"HJxOVA4FaM","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399087887},{"_id":"ByFNCNK6f","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399088688},{"_id":"BJgFNC4Kaf","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399088708},{"_id":"SJWY4REYTz","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399089387},{"_id":"rkqNCEKpG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399089568},{"_id":"B1gq40NtaG","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399089927},{"_id":"BJZcNRNKaG","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399090067},{"_id":"rkf9EA4KTf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399090148},{"_id":"BynV0Etpf","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399091987},{"_id":"HJ6VAEK6f","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399092648},{"_id":"ByzS0NKaG","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399098327},{"_id":"Sy2SCEtTf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399107737},{"_id":"S1lnSAEYTf","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399107755},{"_id":"HkW2B04KTG","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399107778},{"_id":"r1fnSC4KTM","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399107779},{"_id":"HJmhSCNYTz","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399107787},{"_id":"H1H3SRVFaf","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399107788},{"_id":"HyI2r0NFTM","data":"N11A00029","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,50,57],"timestamp":1525399107897},{"_id":"ByvhHRNK6f","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399107928},{"_id":"rkHLCVYpM","data":"N11E00000","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,48,48,48],"timestamp":1525399117388},{"_id":"r14wRNKpz","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525399132466},{"_id":"HkBDANtaf","data":"N11E00100","raw":[78,49,49,69,48,48,49,48,48],"timestamp":1525399132528},{"_id":"BkIBsOKTG","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525414717869},{"_id":"HkxIro_taf","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525414718312},{"_id":"H1uSsdtaz","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525414720324},{"_id":"HkcrsdYpz","data":"N11C00321","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,50,49],"timestamp":1525414722314},{"_id":"HJ3Si_F6G","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525414724332},{"_id":"SJ0HiOKTf","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525414726332},{"_id":"rkxUoOtTG","data":"N11C00321","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,50,49],"timestamp":1525414728402},{"_id":"B1GIsOKpf","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525414730332},{"_id":"HJVLsOFpf","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525414732312},{"_id":"ByLIj_KTM","data":"N11C00321","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,50,49],"timestamp":1525414734361},{"_id":"BJHthOF6f","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415037409},{"_id":"ry8t3dKTM","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415038094},{"_id":"SJOF3_FpM","data":"N11C00315","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,53],"timestamp":1525415040094},{"_id":"By5t2dFaM","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415042104},{"_id":"rkhF2_t6M","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415044095},{"_id":"S10YhdYTz","data":"N11C00315","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,53],"timestamp":1525415046104},{"_id":"r1l9nOtpM","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415048094},{"_id":"Bkz52dK6z","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415050104},{"_id":"S1EchOFaG","data":"N11C00315","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,53],"timestamp":1525415052115},{"_id":"rkEa6uYpM","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415356498},{"_id":"ByxE6TdKaz","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415356499},{"_id":"SJIp6dFaM","data":"N11C00314","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,52],"timestamp":1525415358063},{"_id":"B1O6aOYaG","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415359914},{"_id":"SJ5aTuKTz","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415361943},{"_id":"By3a6OtTz","data":"N11C00314","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,52],"timestamp":1525415363919},{"_id":"By0aTdYaG","data":"N11A00032","raw":[78,49,49,65,48,48,48,51,50],"timestamp":1525415365905},{"_id":"SklATOtTz","data":"N11B00095","raw":[78,49,49,66,48,48,48,57,53],"timestamp":1525415367913},{"_id":"SyfCT_YTf","data":"N11C00314","raw":[78,49,49,67,48,48,51,49,52],"timestamp":1525415369913}]}
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse () at mySuccess

I got this error for my angularjs controller while attempting to convert the JSON Object to javascript object.

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Provide the JSON which you get on `console.log($scope.records.data);`

Comment: Have uploaded the JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse () at mySuccess

That's the typical error message for trying to parse an object literal via `JSON.parse()`, the `o` is coming from the object's stringified version `[object Object]`. Angularjs already parses the JSON, so you don't have to. Change your code from

```
mydata= $scope.records.data;
myobj= JSON.parse(mydata);
```

to

```
myobj = $scope.records.data
```

and omit `JSON.parse()` entirely.

Comment: But why I could not format the string by using the substring() or slice() function?

The purpose of Parse the JSON data is to do formating

Comment: Again, you don't have a string, you have an object literal you're dealing with. An object doesn't have substring, nor slice @ReubenKaiMin